# Unable to access JSON data in Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

i'm getting the a JSON string as a response from the server, however when i'm accessing the objects inside the response i get a message saying undefined

**below is the ajax request i'm making**

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'somefile_url',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {param1: 'value1'},
        })
        .done(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        })
```

**this is the response i get from server in .done(resp)**

```
type: "success"
dump: "{"page_base_url":"http://www.myblog.com/about","page_url_revision":"http://www.myblog.com/about","page_url_alternate":"http://www.myblog.com/about","page_url_shortlink":"http://www.myblog.com/about","page_url_canonical":"http://www.myblog.com/about","page_title":"About US | Blog","page_name":"About Blog","page_type":"about","page_meta_description":"this is a demp with apsotrope 's here and a double quote " here see it's easily parsed and JSON return the data","page_keywords":["my","about","us","know","better"]}"
```

However i'm trying to access the data but shows as undefined.

When i access resp.type it shows `success`(which is the response from server) but when i try to access resp.dump.page_base_url or any other data in that object it shows undefined

I tried resp.dump["page_base_url"] as well but landed with an undefined message.

How do i access this data? Kindly suggest.

Comment: This looks like a simple bug, but I am not sure what is `resp` here? Is it an object, array or json string? Can you share an image of what exactly you get after doing `console.log(resp)` inside `.done`

Comment: Removed my answer suggesting `dataType: 'json' (small caps)`, would the downvoter be kind enough to explain why its not correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing `dump` value first.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'somefile_url',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'JSON',
   data: {param1: 'value1'},
}).done(function(resp) {
   const parsedDump = JSON.parse(resp.dump);

   /* rest of the code */
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not being able to access the data is because,although it looks like an object, is actually a string. So if the server is an endpoint in your control then i would suggest going there and changing it so that it send an object not a string. 
You cannot do `resp.dump.page_base_url` because dump is a string.
A hacky way of accomplishing what you want would be to split the string based on what you want like doing 
`dump.split(":");`

would split it based on colon but again i recommend you check out whats wrong with the backend.

PS. try parsing the object using `JSON.parse(resp.dump)`